how to add multiple interfaces in `/etc/hosts.allow` file?
SSH is listening on all the available 10 Ethernet interfaces in my system. I have tested using nc 160.49.198.97 22 command in Linux. To allow only particular interface and block others, i have created hosts.deny and hosts.allow files in `/etc/ folder.
Below is hosts.deny file
sshd: ALL
Below is hosts.allow file
sshd: 160.49.198.97
Now along with 160.49.198.97, I need to add 160.49.198.185 and 160.49.198.199 also in hosts.allow file. How to add them? Should i separate IP's by comma? or by space ??

TCP Wrappers seem to be slowly dying; for example, Red Hat deprecated them since RHEL 8 release. Not so many people are using them, so I feel like it's under-tested project which can have bugs in the wild (despite the care Wietse Venema puts in his code). I'd advise against it. Better use a properly supported firewall (e.g. iptables, nftables) to control access, if you really need security. It's tempting to close this question as off-topic (not a reasonable business IT management practice).

@Nikita, I need to enable or disable interfaces with hosts file only, not using firewall.

That's very strange requirement. It has to have a strong reason behind it.
